# UIImage color correction

Tags: ios, performance, video, image-processing, avfoundation

I am using `AVFoundation` to play a video by creating a `CGImage` from the `AVFoundation` callback, creating a `UIImage` from the `CGImage` and then displaying the `UIImage` in a `UIImageView`.

I want to apply some color correction to the images before I display them on the screen. What is the best way to colorize the images I'm getting?

I tried using the `CIFilters`, but that requires me to first create a `CIImage` from `AVFoundation`, then colorise it, then create a `CGImage` and then create a `UIImage`, and I'd rather avoid the extra step of creating the `CIImage` if possible.

Additionally, it doesn't seem like the performance of the `CIFilters` is fast enough - at least not when also having to create the additional `CIImage`. Any suggestions for a faster way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look a the GPUImage framework? It won't get you away from using intermediate formats, but the filters run quite a bit faster than CIFilters in most cases. https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Seems like a pretty cool library overall, but don't think it will do what I need, since I need the AVFoundation face detection as well as color correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using an `EAGLContext` instead of a standard `CIContext` is the answer. That gives fast enough performance in creating the colorized images for my needs.

Simple code example here:

On Init:

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setObject: [NSNull null] forKey: kCIContextWorkingColorSpace];
m_EAGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
m_CIContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:m_EAGLContext options:options];
```

Set the color:

```
-(void)setColorCorrection:(UIColor*)color
{  
  CGFloat r,g,b,a;
  [color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];

  CIVector *redVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:r Y:0 Z:0];
  CIVector *greenVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:g Z:0];
  CIVector *blueVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:b];

  m_ColorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
  [m_ColorFilter setDefaults];
  [m_ColorFilter setValue:redVector forKey:@"inputRVector"];
  [m_ColorFilter setValue:greenVector forKey:@"inputGVector"];
  [m_ColorFilter setValue:blueVector forKey:@"inputBVector"];
}
```

On each video frame:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
CGImageRef cgImage = nil;

CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

[m_ColorFilter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage *adjustedImage = [m_ColorFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

cgImage = [m_CIContext createCGImage:adjustedImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];
```